# New messages in EXM 3.3 don't have default values for some reason?

Tags: exm

I have a Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 instance with a fresh install of EXM 3.3.  Everything seems to be set up correctly.  I have set it up so the Newsletter message type is available.  So I can create a new one time message using the Newsletter message type.  However it seems like for some reason Sitecore is not copying over all of the default values for the Newsletter message root whenever I create a new message.

For example, I just went in to EXM and created a new Newsletter message called "Test 5".  If I go to the content tree I notice that there is a message item at the following location:

`/sitecore/content/Email Campaign/Messages/2016/10/12T193103/Test 5`

So that seems correct.  But if I look at the Test 5 item I notice that there is nothing in the Body field. And if I go to `/sitecore/content/Email Campaign/Messages/2016/10/12T193103/Test 5/Newsletter Root` and look at the Presentation Details I notice that there is nothing defined there.  It's like for some reason when Sitecore created the Test 5 item it didn't use any of the default values.  Any idea why?

EDIT: Also, I looked in my log files and I can't see anything that would explain this.

Comment: You say you've set up the Newsletter message type. Does that mean you installed the "Email Experience Manager Sample Newsletter 3.3.0 rev. 160527.zip" package?

Comment: No.  What I meant by that is that I added the Newsletter branch template to the Insert Options for the default node under the One Time Message type.  I haven't installed anything other than EXM 3.3.

Comment: Ok. Please go ahead and install that package then if you want to use the default Newsletter template. The package is part of the downloaded package from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email_Experience_Manager/Email_Experience_Manager_33/Email_Experience_Manager_33_Initial_Release.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In EXM, when creating a new message, a series of events fire that affect the message being created.  For instance, setting the Body field to the correct item.

These events are configured by enabling the `Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentManagement.config` in the EmailExperience config folder.

When issues arise with this functionality, it is normally because of a conflict between other events that might be configured.

I would try disabling any custom events first and see if that solves your issue. If the issue goes away, isolate which custom event is causing the issue and identify whether it's an order of events issue, or some other issue.

Comment: Would issues with these events be logged, normally?

Comment: Depends on the nature of the conflict, for instance if two handlers were actually modifying fields on save, and modifying the same fields, it wouldn't error, but it might not have desired effect.